# Invalid VCS root mapping - 3 errors on my project

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

When I import project to Android Studio, I found this errors:

> - Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/filter_title_awesomeChat').
> - Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/filter_title_awesomeChat').
> - Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processFreeReleaseResources'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>
>   **Invalid VCS root mapping**
>
>   The directory C:\Users\alfayed\Desktop\awesome-chat is registered as a Git root, but no Git repositories were found there.

[Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSqil.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure the project was cloned and not downloaded as a zip into the directory you are using (there should be C:\Users\paula\Git\OpenTripPlanner.git directory on your disk).
and make sure your gpath to git executable is indicating the correct path.

Answer (score 107):

For the **Invalid VCS root mapping error** you can fix it by deleting the `vcs.xml` file located in the `.idea` folder of your project and then rebuild your project.

Comment: Also, grep for the offending name `grep "offending/name/" .idea/* for related errors.  While not building for Android, #pycharm caused the failure in workspace.xml for failing to find a directory marked to be ignored.

Comment: This step in combination with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840874/7329611 step solved my corrupt Android Studio Flutter Project problem

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for, as even after deleting the .git directory the IntelliJ IDEA was repeatedly showing the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

For the `Invalid VCS root mapping` error, you can fix it by deleting the `vcs.xml` file located in the `.idea` folder of your project and then Reopen your IDE.

Answer (score 3):

The three Gradle Build errors seems separate from the invalid VCS root mapping error.

- For the invalid VCS root mapping error, you can go to the root of the project `C:\Users\alfayed\Desktop\awesome-chat`, and create a git repo by `git init`.
- For the three Gradle Build errors, you can debug the details with the source code.

Comment: Does there also show invalid VCS root mapping? Can you add the screen shot after initial a git repo? And what's the detail steps for you to import project to Android studio?

Answer (score 2):

all you need is to delete the vcs.xml file inside an .idea folder this works!

Answer (score 2):

When you clone your project from git make sure you do:

```
git clone --recursive YOUR-GIT-URL
```

or if you have already cloned then to fix it:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove Existing Directory Mapping by following File -> Setting -> Version Control -> Directory Mappings and then click "-".

Make Project

[image: Setting]

Answer (score 1):

For resolving "**Invalid VCS root mapping**"

Make sure the project was cloned and not downloaded as a zip into the directory you are using (there should be C:\Users\alfayed\Desktop\awesome-chat.git directory on your disk).

Answer (score 1):

For the Invalid VCS root mapping error, deleting the .idea folder of your project and then rebuild your project.