# Android studio - Cannot load settings from file app.iml, file does not exist?

Tags: android, android-studio

I faced this when importing projects from online git repos directly using Android studio, turns out the iml file in .idea modules.xml reference, were not being generated.

Comment: For me, the bellow solutions did not work. I deleted the whole `.idea` folder and then reinitialized the project. Mine was an old repo though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Goto project root:

- Delete any .iml files in the whole repo.
- Make sure android studio is closed, and enter ".idea" folder.
- Delete the "modules.xml" file (where the missing files are being referenced).
- Open your project in Android studio, and it will now generate the missing .iml files, as-well as the modules.xml file.
- You will no longer get the annoying popup!

Hope it helps.

Comment: The best solution!!!!

Comment: As stated from Minhas i had to delete the .idea folder entirely to make it work

Answer (score 2):

```
File -> Invalidate cache / restart
```

will definitely solve your problem