# Android application and GitHub

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I have a question, I and my team finished developing our Android project on GitHub

Now we should submit it, how to export the project to ZIP and open it without showing the "Invalid VCS root mapping" error message to our evaluator

I hope my question is clear
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid VCS root mapping - 3 errors on my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311661/invalid-vcs-root-mapping-3-errors-on-my-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Invalid VCS root mapping error you can fix it by deleting the vcs.xml file located in the .idea folder of your project and then rebuild your project.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, can you please just to make sure .. what is the right way to download the project from GitHub to open successfully on the evaluator pc? sorry if my question is considered stupid..

Comment: either you clone or download directly into zip n just unzip it..now open the project on android studio.. for error that u mentioned in your question the answer is already given..

Comment: sorry if i bothered you, but I couldn't find .idea folder ..

Comment: download your code properly...after clicking the project main folder 2nd or 3rd folder will be .idea folder