# IDE is not fetching or pushing to GitHub: Invalid VCS root mapping

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, fetch, webstorm, git-push

Neither the WebStorm nor the PyCharm are able to access GitHub. In particular, both IDE reject to fetch to GitHub and the console shows me this alert:

> Invalid VCS root mapping
> The directory `<Project>/vuex_todo_manager` is registered as a Git root, but no Git repositories were found there.

Then I've configured the Version Control from the Preferences menu and I've deleted the VCS directory "marked in red" and I've left the other option:

[image: WebStorm Version Control window's capture]

After that, the IDE's console shows me the following message:

> /Users/drrecorda/WebStormProjects/vuex_todo_manager/.idea/vcs.xml
> Error:(4,6) Element mapping is not allowed here

That's the code from the `vcs.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
    <mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$" vcs="Git" />
  </component>
</project>
```

Later the console still shows me:

> Auto fetch failed
> unable to access 'https://github.com/JoanRecorda/vuex_todo_manager.git/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443

---

On the other hand also push attempt failed and console shows me:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/JoanRecorda/1001Pythonkatas.git/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443

I really have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: IDE relies on command-line git and the errors that you are having are thrown by git itself. Could you please try to run git operations in cmd.exe/Terminal and see if the issue persists?

Speaking of `Auto Fetch failed` - the error comes from "GitToolBox" plugin that you can disable under Preferences | Plugins or you can configure autofetch in the Preferences | Version Control | GitToolBox

Comment: Have you seen this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311661/invalid-vcs-root-mapping-3-errors-on-my-project

Comment: I've already fixed, but I've solved that after uninstalling PhpStorm... so 'Im not really sure which was the issue.